# TCP data sending each 20ms issue

Tags: java, android, tcp

I'm trying to send data through UDP each 20ms and It's working properly.
But, as I try to use TCP it's not working well and the app gives me the not responding error!
Following code is for sending through UDP

```
public class sMessage implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress local = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.16.254");
        int msg_length=messageStr.length();
        byte[] message = messageStr.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, msg_length,local,server_port);
        s.send(p);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ERROR");
    }
}
}
```

And I use the same Runnable for TCP, but not working correctly!

```
public class sMessage implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.v(TAG, "send");
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 5000);//create a socket
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            PrintWriter ot = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            String s = "1";

            //s+="\r\n";
            //byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
            //os.writeChar(1);
            //os.writeBytes(text);
            //os.writeUTF(String.valueOf("123"));
            ot.println(text);
            ot.flush();
            ot.close();
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ERROR");
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to send data each 10ms by using TCP!
why it is not working properly!??
Thanks in advance for your replies

Comment: it's impossible to guess the reason without looking into the log messages. do you have TCP server socket actually running on port 5000 of "SERVERIP"?

Comment: it makes not much sense to try sending data over TCP so frequently, as TCP is designed to get the confirmation of data sent (UDP does not have confirmation), and it will take much more than 10 ms. for the data to be sent + the confirmation to be received

Comment: TCP is perfectly suitable for sending data every 10ms, and the "data confirmation" @VladyslavMatviienko mentioned does not materially affect timings seen at the application layer. Nevertheless, it is important for us to know how you are executing these runnables, and how you are managing the timing. More code, and the stack traces, are required.

Comment: Thanks for for your useful replies, I did it by just opening socket at onCreate, then put the send method on a loop.Do never open socket on a loop! that's the key for my issue.

Comment: TCP is not suitable for sending timely data every 10ms because of head of line blocking and congestion control. "data confirmation" does affect timings seen at the application layer because the data has to be delivered in order.